# Is it possible to play ultra graphics games online where the actual graphics computing is happening in remote location?

Tags: networking

I had this question for a while that using just high speed internet and some game files on the client end, can we experience the immersive gaming without owning overpriced computer components??

I'm referring to games such as Battlefield 4, Far Cry, etc.

has it been implemented already??

Comment: This might get better answers on [GameDev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It would be the same like e.g. Steam In-Home Streaming, just over Internet, but the "overpriced" computer hardware would just be at a different place and I doubt that anybody would offer it for a free price. It would be a leasing of computing power. Don't know about implementations but someone could use In-Home-Streaming over VPN (performance would be horrible probably).

Comment: an example of a sevice that has attempted this is [Onlive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OnLive) which was shut down after a mixed reception.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While streaming video is no problem (doesn't matter if you're watching YouTube or game feed), control latency is. Input from your controls will have to travel to remote location and then back with video.

Latency is enough of a problem in network games - each realtime multiplayer game has to predict what other players do at this very millisecond, and then deal with conflicts if the prediction was not accurate (this results in, for example, one player being killed after he ducked into cover, because for a second played he was still vulnerable).

Now imagine all of your input having a delay of 100-200-300 milliseconds. While there will not be conflicts (it is just you and the game), imagine racing or shooting or playing Super Mario with such delays!

So, realistically remote gaming is limited to local network, like mentioned Steam streaming.

Comment: My experience with Steam inhouse streaming is already quite mediocre. But that might be because of my really bad wifi access point.

Comment: I agree with you Orc JMR. But what if the server is close enough like in the same city then how much delay we are talking about here??

Comment: For same city it still greatly depends on network infrastructure. But I've just pinged the website of my city's government, and it's still 98 msec - and that's for a simple ping. For video, some more milliseconds will be lost on video compression-decompression.